# Odoo-16 Granting access to different users

Tags: python, linux, odoo-16, odoo-website

I have created multiple websites in odoo. I also created different users and now I want to give them access to different sites but only one website not the rest.
for example: user1 can only edit website1 and when user1 goes to website2 he can only view not edit anything.
how can I accomplish this?
I use odoo-16 on linux manjaro

I tried finding a solution by checking access rights and record rules but I couldn't find anything and I became even more confused.

Comment: did you try to only associate the user with the specific company attached to the website?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @aekis.dev how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can create gorup creatain number of users and restrict the view or menu for particular group

utube link: https://youtu.be/Fsp6lAPHz08?si=7Jh8D_635ombrtpj

Answer (score 0):

It's a little tricky to get it working and mostly need to be tied to the group `Website / Editor and Designer`

I have tested a working example that works modifying the Record Rule `website_designer: Manage Website and qWeb view` to be:

```
[('type', '=', 'qweb'), ('website_id', '=', user.website_id.id)]
```

So you can now associate Users with their Website in the partner form at the end of the `Sales and Purchase` Tab
[image: Setup User/Partner Website]

Or you could manually add the field website_id (it's an stored related to partner_id.website_id field) to the User form like I did in order to visualize it
[image: User Website]

You will then receive a Security Error when the User2 tries to save any changes to the `Website 1` like:
[image]

This is an starting point to prevent different users to be able to edit different websites. There could be more things to improve that but I will prefers to extend it by code in a module to bring a better functionality to Odoo limited capabilities around this